# Does a great work bring benefits to the entire region or just to the 4 cities which built it?

Tags: simcity-2013

In a big region of 16 cities there are 4 great works to build but not every city can built them, just the four which surround them. Will the Great work bring benefits to the entire region or only to the cities surrounding them?

Answer (score 6):

It is only to the 4 cities that built it. Sorry :(

Comment: That is not what I expected :(

Comment: @SadlyNot - Having not played Simcity, I can only assume that if the region played its cards right, each city should benefit from one great work.

Comment: This what I expected. The type of resources generated by Great Works (education, tourists, energy, etc) all need a road connection for agents to travel along.

Comment: @popo if this is the answer your looking for please accept it or tell me what I can do to make it better.

Answer (score 5):

The 16 city regions are broke up into clusters of 4 cities each. **Each 4-city cluster does NOT even "see" or notice the other cluster's Great Work.** Let me show you an example:

[image: Great Work]

I have a Space Center Great Work in the red highlighted portion, but my current city does not even recognize it as being built, because its in a different cluster of the region.

There are regions with more than 4 city cluster to 1 Great Work site, however. Whitewater Valley (5 cities to 1 Great Work) and Reflection Atoll (7 cities to 1 Great Work) both exceed that number.

This is all very contrary to the wording on some of the descriptions of the Great Works (saying that they benefit the entire region).

Also, I do believe most of the Great Works' benefits arrive by road, and that's the main separation reason of the clusters, highway region roads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We can assume that in the big region the 16 cities aren't all connected. Am i right?

Comment: The big region w/ 16 cities is actually 4 small city clusters.

Comment: @Popo They gain benefits from unlocks and such, and I believe if you are connected by a river or rail you can ship materials between cities. That's about all the "connected-ness" you get though.