# How are great works' perks shared between the various cities in the different regions?

Tags: simcity-2013

In regions that have many great works, how are the perks shared?

I have read the responses in the following thread: [Does a great work bring benefits to the entire region or just to the 4 cities which built it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113402/does-a-great-work-bring-benefits-to-the-entire-region-or-just-to-the-4-cities-wh)

However, how does it work when it comes to the 7 cities regions (Edgewater Bay/Reflection Atoll) or the 10 cities region (2x5 Granite Lake)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cities that are clustered to that great work get the benefits of the great work.

The 7 city maps have 1 great work site.  All 7 cities are clustered to it.

The 10 city map has 2 great work sites.  5 cities are clustered to each great work site.

Any given city site benefits from exactly one great work site.